# Google Chrome can't detect my android device but both adb devices and android studio can detect my device

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

Google Chrome can't detect my device using `chrome://inspect/#devices`.
But both `adb devices` and Android Studio can detect it.

[Google Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18qdc.png)

`adb devices` output:
`List of devices attached
58H3Y18807006304        device`

I tried reinstalling chrome, tried removing all apps and extensions but nothing worked.

But when I loaded Ubuntu on Virtual Box and connected my phone in the VM, then chrome inside Ubuntu VM detected my phone.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See [Remote Debugging WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) ...

unless setting `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);` the debug bridge won't connect.

Another possible cause are local ports having non-default values, which may require [port-forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/#reverse-port-forwarding).

This would at least list the local ports in use:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Hi @Martin, I am working on IONIC app and builds are debug build, and I can see my device on other system and in the ubuntu VM. Can you please tell me what port mappings are required?

Comment: @dont.mind.me for IONIC, the `WebView` needs to be set "debuggable"... which commonly happens when building `CordovaLib` in debug mode. this appears to be a Java problem, not a Chrome problem or ADB problem. port mappings can only be setup while knowing their numbers; `adb` also shows them... if it works on one machine, but not the other, the `udev` rules might vary.